# C# linq to sql connection string changed to default setting

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

In a C# desktop application, I am using linq to sql to connect to a sql server 2008 r2 database. The application is setup to point to various databases depending upon the value in the app.config file.

The problem is code in the `*.designer.cs` gets overrriden somehow by `defaults` in the .net problem framework. When this happens the `using system.configuration` gets removed from the application and the `default settings` values are used to get the database connection string values.

When I notice this problem occurs, I need to do the following:

1. place the `using system.configuration` code back into `*.designer.cs` file
2. change the code so the database connection info is obtained from the `app.config file`
3. remove the property settings so the `default` database connections are not used.

Thus can you tell me what is causing this problem to occur and how to solve the problem?

Comment: @JeremyThompson - I don't think you understand what he's saying, the designer is the only place to tell the dbml not to use its own generated connection string , but to force it to use another , and in the code when you write using(datacontext)...  it will automatically use the conn. ctring from the dbml

Answer (score 1):

I have to do this everytime I update the dbml file, its a real pain.  There are 2 things you can try.

First - after updating the dbml, right click anywhere in the dbml, go to properities, then under connection string you should be able to see the one from the web.config,  or app.config that you want.

If it is not in the list , then set it to none, then go into the designer file and do what you have been doing.

Comment: I tried what you recommend, but I still have this problem all the time